# Libreoffice Calc CountIf inconsistent behaviour

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I'm using LibreOffice 4.2.8 and I'm noticing some inconsistent behaviour while using CountIf. I wonder if I'm missing something. When I have the option to use regular expression (Tool->Options->LibreCalc->Calculate->Enable regular expression in formula) I get 0 when using countif on rows that contain some of the characters that would be control a character in a regular expression. In the table below that would be A1,B1,C1. However those same characters by themselves seem to work just fine. In the table below A,B,C. When I turn of regular expression in formula these discrepancies vanish, but I notice that "=" fails. Is this a bug or am I missing some subtlety much like escaping rules on bash?

With regular expressions turned on

```
A     |B   |C (formula in B)
------|----|---------------          
One   |1   |=COUNTIF(A$3:A3,A3)      
Two   |1   |=COUNTIF(A$3:A4,A4)      
(     |1   |=COUNTIF(A$3:A5,A5)      <<<<<<<<<<<<< A
]     |1   |=COUNTIF(A$3:A6,A6)      
[     |1   |=COUNTIF(A$3:A7,A7)      <<<<<<<<<<<<< B
One   |2   |=COUNTIF(A$3:A8,A8)      
Two   |2   |=COUNTIF(A$3:A9,A9)      
One ( |0   |=COUNTIF(A$3:A10,A10)    <<<<<<<<<<<<< A1
Two [ |0   |=COUNTIF(A$3:A11,A11)    <<<<<<<<<<<<< B1
One ] |1   |=COUNTIF(A$3:A12,A12)    
Two ) |0   |=COUNTIF(A$3:A13,A13)    
|     |1   |=COUNTIF(A$3:A14,A14)    <<<<<<<<<<<<< C
One | |0   |=COUNTIF(A$3:A15,A15)    <<<<<<<<<<<<< C1
=     |0   |=COUNTIF(A$3:A16,A16)    
One = |1   |=COUNTIF(A$3:A17,A17)    
+     |1   |=COUNTIF(A$3:A18,A18)    
Two + |0   |=COUNTIF(A$3:A19,A19)    
^     |1   |=COUNTIF(A$3:A20,A20)    
&     |1   |=COUNTIF(A$3:A21,A21)    
*     |1   |=COUNTIF(A$3:A22,A22)    
One ^ |0   |=COUNTIF(A$3:A23,A23)    
Two & |1   |=COUNTIF(A$3:A24,A24)    
One * |2   |=COUNTIF(A$3:A25,A25)
```

With regular expressions turned off

```
A     |B     |C  (formula in B)
------|------|----------
One   |1    |=COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)
Two   |1    |=COUNTIF(A$1:A2,A2)
(     |1    |=COUNTIF(A$1:A3,A3)
]     |1    |=COUNTIF(A$1:A4,A4)
[     |1    |=COUNTIF(A$1:A5,A5)
One   |2    |=COUNTIF(A$1:A6,A6)
Two   |2    |=COUNTIF(A$1:A7,A7)
One ( |1    |=COUNTIF(A$1:A8,A8)
Two [ |1    |=COUNTIF(A$1:A9,A9)
One ] |1    |=COUNTIF(A$1:A10,A10)
Two ) |1    |=COUNTIF(A$1:A11,A11)
|     |1    |=COUNTIF(A$1:A12,A12)
One | |1    |=COUNTIF(A$1:A13,A13)
=     |0    |=COUNTIF(A$1:A14,A14)     <<<<<<<<
One = |1    |=COUNTIF(A$1:A15,A15)
+     |1    |=COUNTIF(A$1:A16,A16)
Two + |1    |=COUNTIF(A$1:A17,A17)
^     |1    |=COUNTIF(A$1:A18,A18)
&     |1    |=COUNTIF(A$1:A19,A19)
*     |1    |=COUNTIF(A$1:A20,A20)
One ^ |1    |=COUNTIF(A$1:A21,A21)
Two & |1    |=COUNTIF(A$1:A22,A22)
One * |1    |=COUNTIF(A$1:A23,A23)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the problem with the "=" you could simply concatenate a "=" as first character in the criteria of `COUNTIF`. That means look for equality only:

```
=COUNTIF(A$3:A3,"="&A3)
```

This way you can also count empty cells. This `COUNTIF` does not normally.

For the problem with the regular expressions the only way I know is to `SUBSTITUTE` all possible dangerous characters with the escaped ones.

```
=COUNTIF(A$3:A3,"="&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A3,"+","\+"),"|","\|"),"(","\("),")","\)"),"[","\["))
```

Above formula is not completely of course. And if completed then it will be very long.